# how to print in single line with an inline if else statement in python 2.7

Tags: python, if-statement, inline

I am using python2.7. The below code works if I remove `,` in the print statement.
but that prints the values in different lines. I want to print in same line with an inline `if-statement` if possible.

Here is what I have:

```
def binary(x):

   for i in [128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1]:
      #if x&i: print 1,
      #else: print 0,
       print 1, if x&i else 0

binary(127)
```

It throws the following syntax error:

```
File "binary.py", line 6
    print 1, if x&i else 0
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the comma at the *end*:

```
print 1 if x&i else 0,
```

You are using a conditional expression, of the form `true_expr if condition_expr else false_expr`, and the part *before* the `if` (`true_expr`) is part of that expression. you are printing the outcome of that expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
def binary(x):
   for i in [128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1]:
       print 1 if x&i else 0,

binary(127)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have stated, putting the comma at the *end* of the `print` line will solve your problem.

However, there is a far easier way to achieve what you want if you use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> def binary(x):
...     return " ".join(format(n, "08b"))
...
>>> print binary(127)
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
>>>
```

This method does the same thing as your function, only it is a lot more concise and efficient.

Comment: what does the "08b" stands for?

Comment: It stands for "8-bit binary".  In other words, the binary will be 8 characters long (like you want it).  Having the `0` in there makes it fill in 0's at the start until it reaches 8 characters.  Without it, the output would be `"1 1 1 1 1 1 1"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 127

>>> [1 if ele & x else 0 for ele in [128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

You can even use,

```
x = 127

>>> [[0,1][bool(ele & x)] for ele in [128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```